# Accessing and filling array(s) by its name in the main method of a java class (created via member function )

Tags: java, arrays, oop, element

I have a program in which I should create a class that has a member function which creates arrays of different simple data types. I instantiate a class in the main method, i.e I make a object of this class, and invoke the createArray method. When I try to fill - in the array with the same type of data using `Arrays.fill(name,startIndex, endIndex, value)` it could not find an array which such name. I would like to ask you why is that?

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;

    public class MainClass {
      public void createArray(){
      int [] ints = new int[10];
      }
    }
    class Test{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            MainClass mcl = new MainClass();
            mcl.createArray();
            for (int i = 0;i<10;i++){
                //cannot resolve symbol ints - why?
                Arrays.fill(ints,0,9,8);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to change `createArray` method signature, you can store your array in a class attribute and create getter method for it.
Here is some code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class MainClass {

    private int[] ints;

    public void createArray(){
        this.ints = new int[10];
    }

    public int[] getInts() {
        return ints;
    }
}
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainClass mcl = new MainClass();
        mcl.createArray();
        for (int i = 0;i<10;i++){
            //cannot resolve symbol ints - why?
            Arrays.fill(mcl.getInts(),0,9,8);
        }
    }
}
```

But since `createArray` is already public, better approach is probably to change it's signature to return `int[]`, example code for that case:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class MainClass {

    private int[] ints;

    public int[] createArray(){
        this.ints = new int[10];
        return ints;
    }

}
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainClass mcl = new MainClass();
        mcl.createArray();
        for (int i = 0;i<10;i++){
            //cannot resolve symbol ints - why?
            Arrays.fill(mcl.createArray(),0,9,8);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some issues with your code, a simpler version of which is available below:

```
public class MainClass {
  public void createArray(){
       //This lives only in here. It is not available outside.
       int [] ints = new int[10];
  }
}
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainClass mcl = new MainClass();
        mcl.createArray();
        for (int i = 0;i<10;i++){
            //cannot resolve symbol ints - why?
            Arrays.fill(ints,0,9,8);
        }
    }
}
```

In the code you have created, `ints` exists only within the `createArray` method. Once that the execution steps out of this method, this array is no longer available and marked for garbage collection.

To go around this, you would need to change your method signature to `return` an array of type `int` (so that when you call the `createArray` method, this method gives you back the array it created). You would then need to make sure that you *capture* the array that is returned in the main class. This would then allow you to perform operations on it.

Answer (score 1):

The `int` variable is defined only in the scope of `createArray` and not outside. You should return it if you need it outside.

Here is some lecture about [Java variable scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/)

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

1. ints is not in the scope of the main class, Its in the create array. You can do something like this:

```
class MainClass {
  int [] ints = new int[10];

  public void createArray()
  {int [] ints = new int[10]; }

}
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainClass mcl = new MainClass();
        mcl.createArray();
        for (int i = 0;i<10;i++){
            //mcl.ints not just ints
            Arrays.fill(mcl.ints,0,9,8);
        }
    }
}
```

2. You have to make Test class public as it has the main method and save the file with Test.java